# BAT: how to run Python Script and restart the process after 1 hour

Tags: python, batch-file

I want to run and restart a specific python script on X time.

I'm aware of the following code but I'm unaware of how to make it kill the ongoing python process and start it over again after X time.

```
@echo off
python main.py
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule it as a cron job or a periodic job.

Library

```
pip install apscheduler
```

Import

```python
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
```

Cron Job:

```python
scheduler = BlockingScheduler()


def hello():
    print("HELLO")
    
    
scheduler.add_job(hello, 'cron', hour="*/1")
scheduler.start()
```

Or you can schedule it to run every one hour

```python
scheduler = BlockingScheduler()


def hello():
    print("HELLO")
    
    
scheduler.add_job(hello, 'interval', hours=1)
scheduler.start()
```